# Schedule a member function to run periodically

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a member function to run periodically.

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    # run every 10 seconds
    def periodic(self):
        [print(a) for a in self.array]

    def insert(self, a):
        self.array.append(a)
```

Most of the libraries and sample code I've seen for this type of scheduling don't work well for member functions. Are there any specific libraries or techniques I can use to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Can you show what you found that works for normal functions and supposedly doesn't work for member functions?

Comment: I was trying to use `apscheduler` to schedule a member function from the constructor. However, I now see that isn't necessary for my situation and scheduling a member function from outside the class works just fine.